# How can I "permute" an ordered pair over all the permutations of say $S_4$?

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation, group-theory

I want to make an action table of the symmetric group (say $S_4$) acting on the set of unordered pairs of distinct vertices of a square. I have the list of such pairs:

```
Level[Table[Table[{i, j}, {i, j + 1, 4}], {j, 1, 3}], {2}]
```

I want to map each element of this list to the unordered pair corresponding to a vertex permutation of $S_4$.  For example: the pair `{3,2}` under the action of `{2,1,4,3} = Cycles[{{1,2},{3,4}]` would correspond to the pair `{4,1}`.

Comment: `PermutationReplace` may be the function you're looking for. The output of your example can be obtained for instance with `PermutationReplace[{3, 2}, Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]]`.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making an answer from my comment.

---

**Notation**

```
list = Level[Table[Table[{i, j}, {i, j + 1, 4}], {j, 1, 3}], {2}]

(* {{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}} *)
```

**Proposition**

```
PermutationReplace[list, Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]]

(* {{1, 2}, {4, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 4}} *)
```